# How to configure a mirror setting for internal /external repository access

Tags: maven-2, repository, archiva

My ~/.m2/settings.xml has a mirrors element which points to an internal repository based on Apache Archiva. But in a home network, mvn tries to timeout trying to look for the internal repository which is no longer accessible. How to configure the settings.xml for internal / external use?

Answer (score 1):

instead use virtual host in etc/hosts. You need to use it also in settings.xml
when you at work provide internal host adres - at home - external.

## 192.168.1.15  mavenmirror

## 84.16.77.25   mavenmirror

and use this host in you settings.xml

Comment: where does this IP (84.16.77.25) point to, is it an external maven repository

Comment: @usovmv - can you kindly clarify